# US Passport stamped in UK for 6 months twice

Tags: usa, uk, customs-and-immigration

[image: passport photo]

My wife and I are from the US (retirees) traveling to and from the UK and were stamped in twice on different dates for 6 months each time. My question is which of these stamps is Border Force going to accept? We would like to use the second 5/15/2019 as this would allow us a longer stay.

Thanks in advance for the responses

Comment: Every time you leave and reenter the UK, you receive a **FRESH** entry stamp and duration. Note that if you continue entering and leaving the UK and spending more time there, at some point you will be turned away at the airport.

Answer (score 6):

Each of these stamps gives you the ability to stay in the country for up to 6 months from the date you entered.  The key word here is "STAY".  Once you leave the country, your entry is over, and you have no right to stay in the country any further (which isn't an issue, because you've already left!)

Thus your "6 April" stamp was valid from the 6th of April, up until whatever date you next left the UK.  At that point, your time is up - even though you were in the country for a lot less than 6 months.  At this time, that stamp serves little purpose other than as a historical record of your entry.

The "15 May" stamp is valid from the 15th of May until EITHER 6 months after that date, or until you leave the UK again, whichever occurs first.

So given these pair of stamps, you are allowed stay into the UK until around the middle of November, 2019.

Answer (score 5):

Obviously, you left the UK after the first entry, or you couldn't have entered again. Immigration is going to believe their own date stamps, so the latest one is valid.
There is nothing to be worried about.